# What is the relation of memory and PLD to (synchronous) sequential circuits?

Tags: digital-logic, memory, programmable-logic

In Mona's Digital Design book,

> Chapter  5    outlines the formal procedures for analyzing and designing clocked (syn-
> chronous) sequential circuits. The gate structure of several types of flip‐flops is presented
> together with a discussion on the difference between level and edge triggering. Specific
> examples are used to show the derivation of the state table and state diagram when
> analyzing a sequential circuit. A number of design examples are presented with empha-
> sis on sequential circuits that use D‐type flip‐flops. Behavioral modeling in Verilog HDL
> for sequential circuits is explained. HDL Examples are given to illustrate Mealy and
> Moore models of sequential circuits.

> Chapter  6    deals with various sequential circuit components such as registers, shift
> registers, and counters. These digital components are the basic building blocks from
> which more complex digital systems are constructed. HDL descriptions of shift registers
> and counter are presented.

> Chapter   7     deals  with  random  access  memory  (RAM)  and  programmable  logic
> devices. Memory decoding and error correction schemes are discussed. Combinational
> and sequential programmable devices such as ROMs, PLAs, PALs, CPLDs, and FPGAs
> are presented.

> Chapter  8    deals with the register transfer level (RTL) representation of digital sys-
> tems. The algorithmic state machine (ASM) chart is introduced. A number of examples
> demonstrate the use of the ASM chart, ASMD chart, RTL representation, and HDL
> description in the design of digital systems. The design of a finite state machine to con-
> trol a datapath is presented in detail, including the realistic situation in which status
> signals from the datapath are used by the state machine that controls it. This chapter is
> the most important chapter in the book as it provides the student with a systematic
> approach to more advanced design projects.

I was wondering what relation is between memory (RAM, ROM) and PLD (ROM, PLA, PAL, CPLD, FPGA) in Ch 7, and the other topics such as (synchronous) sequential circuits in Ch 5,   their specific examples registers and counters in Ch 6, and  the register transfer level (RTL) representation of digital systems in Ch 8, if any?

- Are memory and PLD in Ch 7 some examples or applications of  (synchronous) sequential circuits in Ch 5?
- Are memory and PLD in Ch 7 introduced   as alternatives to the storage elements (latches, and flip-flops) introduced in (synchronous) sequential circuits in Ch 5, and therefore are they used in (synchronous) sequential circuits?

Thanks.

Comment: Think about where you *find* memories, especially those of the addressable multi word type you seem to be asking about.

Comment: Thanks. Could you be more specific and explicit? If any confusion, I was asking about what relation is between memory/PLD and (synchronous) sequential circuits.

Comment: Still I am not sure what your comments meant, as far as my questions are concerned.

Comment: You are not really asking a proper *design* question for this site.  There isn't really a "relation" between the technologies.  If you have a design project where you need to use both, then you'll have to think about how they might *interact*.  Or you could spend some time thinking about how these things are actually *used* in useful systems.  It's worth noting you are relatively unlikely to design synchronous circuitry today, and not simply buy it condensed into a chip - custom synchronous circuitry (in an FPGA, etc) is mostly used in specialized niche applications and school-like projects.

Comment: Eg, the synchronous system you are likely most familiar with is the computer you are posting from.

Comment: @ChrisStratton  My post is not to ask interaction between technologies, but how  they are related as topics during study. My post already mentioned the book. I don't think you are commenting to address my questions.

Comment: That's the problem: **they aren't related**.  The only way this makes any sense is to consider their possible *interaction* in a system.  You need to stop thinking in terms of the book, and start thinking in terms of the sorts of real systems it is describing *distinct* parts of.  Consider for example how a classic stored-program computer works.

Comment: @ChrisStratton right now I am not changing what I am reading: digit circuits. I am asking question which arise during my reading: are memory and PLD applications/examples of  (synchronous) sequential circuits, or are they used by (synchronous) sequential circuits as alternatives to storage elements e.g. flipflops?

Comment: The question which arises in the bigger picture that I am looking at is: are memory and PLD applications/examples of  (synchronous) sequential circuits, or are they used by (synchronous) sequential circuits as alternatives to storage elements e.g. flipflops?

Comment: That's **not a meaningful question**.  The fact that you keep pounding away insistently on it only demonstrates you've not understood the subject matter.  And you are not likely to understand it, until you consider how these work together - eg, compare a simple synchronous system like a state machine to the sort of synchronous system you are actually used to using (a computer).  If you're not able to picture the register file, ALU, control circuitry and memory which comprise a "computer" you should go study that first, as it's what would make these topics make sense to you.

Comment: What you are doing right now is akin to asking about the relationship between engines and wings, while refusing to consider the a diagram of a whole airplane.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I said nothing beyond my post. I think you think much more than what I wrote in my post.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I don't have clear understanding and plan yet about digital circuits and computer parts. I am reading about digital circuits, because of interest in how logic is used, and I am reading about logic, which is my current interest.

Answer (score 1):

Re: "I was wondering what relation is between memory (RAM, ROM) and PLD (ROM, PLA, PAL, CPLD, FPGA), and the other topics such as (synchronous) sequential circuits"

These are all things that you might use to create (synchronous) sequential circuits.

Re: "Are memory and PLD some examples or applications of (synchronous) sequential circuits"

PLDs can be either asynchronous, or synchronous.

Memory often used to be asynchronous, but these days it is more commonly synchronous. Even the asynchronous ones were used in circuits that were largely synchronous.

Re: "Are memory and PLD introduced as alternatives to the storage elements (latches, and flip-flops) introduced in (synchronous) sequential circuits,

PLDs may well include latches, and flip-flops. You would use a PLD as an alternative to discrete logic chips, and possibly latches, to form part of a circuit.

Memory is like a very large array of latches, although the implementation might be substantially different. There are spoecific cases where you could memory in place of latches. Think of memory as a warehouse and a latch as a storage box, then consider how you would think of them as alternatives.

Re: "and therefore are they used in (synchronous) sequential circuits?"
Yes, they are used in (synchronous) sequential circuits.

I have not read the book that you mention. The outline sounds perfectly reasonable. The detail, I don't know.